# How to understand the EIRP criteria in 47 CFR § 15.519 for UWB device?

Tags: antenna, communication, radio

I have difficulties to understand the EIRP critera in [47 CFR § 15.519](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/15.519) for UWB device.It says,

(c)...a device...shall not exceed the following average limits when measured using a resolution bandwidth of 1 MHz:

```
+------------------+-------------+
| Frequency in MHz | EIRP in dBm | 
+------------------+-------------+
| 960 -   1610     | −75.3       |
| 1610 -  1990     | −63.3       |
| 1990 -  3100     | −61.3       |
| 3100 - 10600     | −41.3       |
| Above 10600      | −61.3       |
+------------------+-------------+
```

and

(d)...shall not exceed the following average limits when measured using a resolution bandwidth of no less than 1 kHz:

```
+------------------+-------------+
| Frequency in MHz | EIRP in dBm |
+------------------+-------------+
| 1164-1240        | −85.3       |
| 1559-1610        | −85.3       |
+------------------+-------------+
```

and 
(e) There is a limit on the peak level of the emissions contained within a 50 MHz bandwidth centered on the frequency at which the highest radiated emission occurs, fM. That limit is 0 dBm EIRP.

for this (e), as further explained in [§ 15.521](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/15.521) part (g) that if a resolution bandwidth is not 50MHz, 
one can use `20*log*(RBW/50)` dBm, where RBW is the real resolution bandwidth in use.

My understanding is:

(1)for example for 960-1610MHz, <-75.3 dBm with resolution bandwidth of 1MHz means
the power density is -75.3 dBm/MHz, which means
in every 1MHz section of this frequency range, the total transmitted power of the device in this 1MHz range should be less then -75.3 dBm.

(2) But I don't undersand why with 1KHz resolution bandwidth, in 1164~1240MHz, EIRP in dBm is -83.5. I would guess -75.3dBm-30dBm=-105.3dBm because 1KHz is just 1/1000 of 1MHz, and the total power in this bandwidth would be 30dB less.

(3) I don't understand § 15.521(g), why use `20*log*(RBW/50)` dBm, rather than `10*log(RBW/50)`

Would you please help me to understand this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't undersand why with 1KHz resolution bandwidth, in 1164~1240MHz, EIRP in dBm is -83.5. I would guess -75.3dBm-30dBm=-105.3dBm because 1KHz is just 1/1000 of 1MHz, and the total power in this bandwidth would be 30dB less.

You're assuming that essentially the same power density would be allowed in all allowed bands.

That's not the case.

UWB regulation was the result of half a decade of intense lobbying. And if you'd ask me, personally, that legislation has led to commercial infeasibility of basically any relevant UWB technology, back when UWB was a hot topic.

> \$20\log(RBW/50)\$ dBm, rather than \$10\log(RBW/50)\$

I must admit I don't know.

Comment: Thank you @Marcus Müller. I'd say I agree with you if my understanding is correct. firstly, I now notice that 1164~1240MHz[A] is not 960~1160MHz[B], so having different criteria in principle is ok. So now the problem is it looks that when pass for [A] it will probably fail for [B] for UWB signal. My answer is: to [B], [A] is a relaxed critera, because asking for -105dBm is assuming the spectrum is very smooth, but actually that is not possible.

Comment: Curiously, I would like to know what is the legislation when you say in '...that legislation has led to commercial infeasibility of basically any relevant UWB technology'?

Comment: exactly the FCC rules you cite, and their European counterparts. Not so sure about Japan.

Comment: Thank you @Marcus Müller, but I see quite a few applications with UWB devices has passed the FCC certifcation test. And now Apple has UWB in iphone 11. How to understand this? Another question besides the 20log thing is about the EIRP <=0dBm for 50MHz RWB, I don't understand this: even with the maxium -41.3dBm/MHz(7.4e-5mW/MHz) for 1MHz RWB, 50MHz RWB means 3.71e-3mW/50MHz=-24.3dBm in 50MHz, it can by no way get 0dBm, am I wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: UWB was new and a potentially big market around 2005. That it now, 15 years later, finally has some single-vendor application is a testiment to the fact you simply couldn't build working, financially viable products given the complex regulations back in 2005!

Comment: Thank you @Marcus Mülle. I see your point.

Comment: I hope to give some feedback on 20*log() stuff. I found some interesting discussions on this back to 2004 [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=dvzidia7W4sC&pg=PA24572&lpg=PA24572&dq=10log(%F0%9D%91%85%F0%9D%90%B5%F0%9D%91%8A/50)&source=bl&ots=kROFHqSUgo&sig=ACfU3U3UVdJIlYU7inSM3W3yCKktKqTvgQ&hl=en&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-3vzF3dvoAhVRAp0JHT55AhYQ6AEwAHoECAwQKQ#v=onepage&q=10log(%F0%9D%91%85%F0%9D%90%B5%F0%9D%91%8A%2F50)&f=false), second report and order, section 18, with footnote 47. So basically, the answer is complete now.